# How can I rearrange divs in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have three divs like below

```
<div class="col-lg-4"> A</div>
<div class="col-lg-4"> B </div>
<div class="col-lg-4"> C </div>
```

Basically for xs devices, it becomes like

A

B

C

However, I want it like

A

C

B

How can I do that?

Comment: Well, it seems like so. However, other stackoverflow question is not exactly the same as this. The example one divides into 2/2 (with the 2nd right column dividing again into 2/2 vertically). That is much different than what I need where all are vertically  aligned. Using the pull/push does not work for my case. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript `sort()` function:

Example: *(do not copy/paste)*

```js
var obj = [];
var example = ["A", "C", "B"];
$.each($("div"), function(index, value) {
  
  obj[index] = $(this);
});

obj.sort(function(a, b) {
  var A = example.indexOf(a.text().trim());
    var B = example.indexOf(b.text().trim());
      if (A < B) {
    return -1;
    }
    if (A > B) {
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});

$("body").prepend(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4"> A</div>
<div class="col-lg-4"> B </div>
<div class="col-lg-4"> C </div>
```

Use it to learn not to copy ;-)

Comment: I guess javascript is the only solution for this. I was thinking of using something similar too. However, I was hoping there already is some unknown bootstrap class I am not aware of that can do this for me without having to add more javascript

Comment: Sorry JQ, not CSS :) Stupid me

Comment: @HelloUniverse Hi, it depens, you can get much more clean result with JQ/JS or even JS along, data() is an very good option. CSS only solution are in the wild but some not very well supported.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap this is easy to solve this in html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12"> A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4 col-xs-12"> C </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-4 col-xs-12"> B </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/x2w9nw9s/

Comment: hmm I thought the same.. Must be a bug in my code... some other css code inside the div. Thanks. Yes My question is definitely a repeat then.

Answer (score 0):

Swap B and C code lines and you are done.

Comment: That is not an option, I've had this issue too

Answer (score 0):

You can order your divs with css Using the order property.

```
    <div class="col-lg-4" id="A"> A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" id="B">  B </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" id="C"> C </div>
```

The CSS

```
    #A{order:1;}
    #B{order:3;}
    #C{order:2;}
```

If you want that for different screen size to be something else just use media queries!

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the order property. HOwever, it is not valid for IE < 11. Thanks for the a answ